# AttributeError: 'ContainerGroupsOperations' object has no attribute 'delete'

Tags: azure

I run the following "az container delete" on old cli version successfully. However, when I upgraded to 2.28.0, it failed with error

`az container delete --subscription xx --resource-group xx --name xx`

```
Errors:
The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
'ContainerGroupsOperations' object has no attribute 'delete'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/cli.py", line 231, in invoke
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 657, in execute
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 720, in _run_jobs_serially
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 691, in _run_job
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 328, in __call__
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/container/custom.py", line 66, in delete_container
AttributeError: 'ContainerGroupsOperations' object has no attribute 'delete
```

Comment: Seeing this as well

Comment: I have also added a workaround to my solution

Comment: This should work now as of version 2.29.0

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue introduced by Microsoft updating Az CLI to version 2.28.0.

There is no solution other that downgrade at the moment but MS is acknowledged.
You can track the track their responses in the official repo:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/19475

Still, there are some workarounds to address it.

*Using REST API:*

```
RESOURCE_GROUP=my-rg
ACI_CONTAINER_NAME=containername
SUBSCRIPTION_ID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
az rest --method delete \
        --uri "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/${RESOURCE_GROUP}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/${ACI_CONTAINER_NAME}?api-version=2019-12-01" \
        --subscription ${SUBSCRIPTION_ID}
```

*Using PowerShell:*

```
Remove-AzContainerGroup -Name ${var.resourceName} -ResourceGroupName ${var.resourceGroup} -Confirm:$False
```

Comment: Update: This was fixed in 2.30 CLI version.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error at DevOps jobs, week ago everything was successful. Didn't find any possibilities how to change `az` version from UI.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/set-up-fixed-az-cli-version-in-my-pipeline/960733

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).